# Mysql- update row from one table based on distinct value from another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table Users which has a column MemberID
There is another table called UserMembers, this table have for same users multiple MemberID's. 
Now, I need to populate the Users table MemberID with only 1 value from UserMembers table, so if it has 3 value I want the minimum value.
I tried

```
UPDATE Users 
SET MemberID = (SELECT DISTINCT m.MemberID FROM UserMembers 
um INNER join Users u on  um.UserID = u.UserID
        ORDER BY um.CreatedDT ASC LIMIT 1);
```

But this is not the right query. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can get the minimum value of `MemberID` for every `UserID` from the `UserMembers` table. Join this to the `Users` table using `UserID`, and set this minimum value in the `Users` table.

```
UPDATE Users AS u
JOIN 
(SELECT UserID, MIN(MemberID) AS minMemberID
 FROM UserMembers 
 GROUP BY UserID
) AS dt 
  ON dt.UserID = u.UserID 
SET u.MemberID = dt.minMemberID
```